# HTML/CSS image grid line up of images

Tags: html, css

I am making a website using HTML and CSS, I started on creating a section that will hold 9 images of different sizes. After I had made all of the different sizes and inserted them into the website it didn't turn out how I wanted it to. I was hoping it would turn out something like this:
[Image of grid I was hoping for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYW41.png)

```css
section {
  background-color: black;
  width: 1346px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="http://s30.postimg.org/njfrtgaoh/300x200.png" align="top-right" alt="" />
  <img src="http://s11.postimg.org/v0d12pcyr/200x100_2.png" align="top" alt="" />
  <img src="http://s22.postimg.org/s8jfeeiep/500x400.png" align="top-right" alt="" />
  <img src="http://s22.postimg.org/uxiti6d9t/200x200_2.png" align="top-right" alt="" />
  <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/463k9fm8j/146x100.png" align="top" alt="" />
  <img src="http://s14.postimg.org/prasnic9d/200x100.png" align="top" alt="" />
  <img src="http://s30.postimg.org/hz3aitbtd/500x200.png" align="top-right" alt="" />
  <img src="http://s8.postimg.org/56vmkw3kl/200x200.png" align="top-right" alt="" />
  <img src="http://s23.postimg.org/670g2cmaz/146x300.png" align="top" alt="" />
</section>
```

With the images you will have to look and Imagen them but a bit to the right so it will fit in.

Comment: i know you are looking for html/css way to achieve this, i am not sure whether you will be able to get it like that. an easier approach will be using something like http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/

Comment: I would recommend using a plugin like Masonry.js. Still you can reproduce this with css and html. I would recommend using a css framework like bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider using [Masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/).
Have a look at this example: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/vLeBLV

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have just tried this and put in my images into the divs but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can start working from this fiddle I made for you: https://jsfiddle.net/vc7tdpzz/

```
  var container = document.querySelector('#grid');
  var masonry = new Masonry(container, {
  columnWidth: 100,
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
  });
```

Comment: Okay thank you I have finally managed to get the first layer after a good half hour poking around at it. It's just the second layer I can't seem to get it into a full rectangle. **You may need to create a .html file to see it.**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/midwackcan/u5ue8the/)